# MySQL: Calculate intermediate value at a given timestamp (Linear interpolation)

Tags: mysql

Given the following table, I want to select the value of each ID at exactly 00:00:00. When there's an entry at this exact time, return it, otherwise calculate it with linear interpolation (an imaginary graph line between the nearest values before and after 00:00:00). If there's no value after the given time yet, return the last value, or use linear interpolation from the last two points.

```
ID|Timestamp|Value
1|2015-01-01 23:00:00|90
1|2015-01-02 01:00:00|110
2|2015-01-01 23:00:00|210
2|2015-01-02 01:00:00|190
3|2015-01-02 00:00:00|50
4|2015-01-01 23:00:00|100
5|2015-01-01 22:00:00|80
5|2015-01-01 23:00:00|90
```

Result:

```
ID|Value
1|100
2|200
3|50
4|100
5|100
```

Is this possible with MySQL only and how?

Comment: It is possible in MySQL.  It would be much easier in a database that supports window functions (which would be just about any other database).

Comment: @Mihai: No, 5 would be 85 at 22:30:00. At 00:00:00 it would be 90 (23:00:00) +10 = 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's split it into single entries like #3 versus double entries (the rest):

```
( SELECT ID, value FROM tbl GROUP BY ID HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 )
UNION ALL
( ... ) -- This needs interpolation code, below
ORDER BY ID;
```

To separate the pair of rows is tricky since there is no good way to do "groupwise-max".  So, instead, I will work with @variables and walk through the table in order.

To round to the nearest midnight might be `ROUND(... / 86400) * 86400` .  The potential problem is the time_zone you are in.  I don't feel like fixing that.

```
SELECT ID, val FROM (
SELECT  ID,
        IF(ID != @prevID, '1st', '2nd') AS picker,  -- See WHERE filter, below
        @ts = timestamp,   -- Need an INT here, not sure that is what I have
        @dts = @ts - @prev_ts,
        @dval = value - @prev_val,
        @midnight := ROUND(@ts / 86400) * 86400,  -- DST issues?
        value + (@midnight - @ts) * (@dval / @dts) AS val, -- interpolate
        @prev_id = ID,
        @prev_ts = @ts,
        @prev_val = value
    FROM ( SELECT @prevID := 0 ) AS Initialize
    JOIN tbl
    ORDER BY ID, timestamp
) AS x
WHERE picker = '2nd'
ORDER BY ID
```

Put that monster as the second part of the UNION.